# gunicorn: Failed to find attribute 'app' in module

Tags: python, gunicorn, sanic

Hi I am trying to run,

```
gunicorn --bind localhost:8000 --worker-class sanic_gunicorn.Worker module:app
```

where I have following files

```
# ls
build                            
setup.py
dist                             
module         
module.egg-info 
venv

#cd module

#ls
__init__.py
__pycache__
__main__.py
app.py
```

content of `__main__.py` is as follows

```
from module.app import create_app_instance


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app_instance()
    app.run()
```

and content of app.py is

```
#some imports

def create_app_instance():
    app = Sanic(name = "app_name")
    .....
    return app
```

I am using Sanic web framework and when I am running it's dev server as `python -m module` it works fine

```
python3 -m module
[2021-06-16 22:31:36 -0700] [80176] [INFO] Goin' Fast @ http://127.0.0.1:8000
[2021-06-16 22:31:36 -0700] [80176] [INFO] Starting worker [80176]
```

can someone let me know what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is that there's no `app` exposed inside the module. You have the `create_app_instance()` method but this is not called.

I would suggest for you to refactor your code as follows. File structure would be:

```
./wsgi.py
./module/__init__.py
```

And the contents of those files as below:

**.\wsgi.py**

```py
from module import create_app_instance


app = create_app_instance()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**.\module\__init__.py**

```py
# this is the contents of your current app.py
#some imports

def create_app_instance():
    app = Sanic(name = "app_name")
    .....
    return app
```

and then the gunicorn line to start the server would be (please note the comment from [The Brewmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68013464/gunicorn-failed-to-find-attribute-app-in-module/68015901#comment120245734_68015901) below):

```
gunicorn --bind localhost:8000 --worker-class sanic_gunicorn.Worker wsgi:app
```

What this does is it calls the exposed `app` instance inside `wsgi.py`. The `__main__.py` is not needed, and the code from your `app.py` has been moved to the `__init__.py`

I highly advise you to read through documentation/tutorials for `Application Factory Pattern` for Flask. The principle itself is the same as for Sanic, but there's more articles that describe the principle for Flask...

Comment: One of the Sanic maintainers here. I would agree with this answer. The only thing I'd like to add that unless there are specific features you need from gunicorn that you avoid using it. Or, if you must use it, I would suggest you use it with the uvicorn worker. You will get more performance. The Sanic gunicorn worker is an old compat and is not very performant.

Answer (score 0):

If the application is launched using the `gunicorn app:app` command,
then gunicorn will load the app module (app.py) and look for the app variable.

Since the `app` module is loaded, **name** will be set to `app` rather than `__main__`.

Therefore, a simple fix is:

```py
from module.app import create_app_instance


if __name__ == 'app':
    app = create_app_instance()
    app.run()
```